# Calendar Page in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can I add a view controller with a calendar in my app?
Looking at all the other examples, I can't use KAL or the TAPKU library because they keep presenting bugs and I also don't really want to rely on external code. Any simple code to present my calendar.
Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible with current sdk You need to use own calender or third party. that at this stage, there are no published URLs for Calendar that lets you do this...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this too in one of my apps, but sadly this feature is not built into iOS.